# New Search Console - Google's rare query note, but no query filter applied?

Tags: google-search-console

A couple of screen shots below show a difference which has me stumped.

[image: Screenshot showing three filters applied - so fart so good]

[image: Additonal page filter - WTF?]

The only difference between the two screen shots is an additional **page filter**:- *include URLs containing somesite.co.uk*

**Question**

Why is it reducing the metrics since Google's note (see link to it below) as there's **no query filter applied** in either screenshot?

**Observations, notes, info:**

Previously adding the page filter increased the Impressions, Clicks, etc metrics, still evident in the above before Googles note. Now, it reduces Impressions dramatically (in this example) post Google's note.

I never confirmed why adding the include url containing somesite.co.uk page filter increased the metrics previously, but had a theory it was probably around searches with query info and searches without.

Google's note dated 19 August 2018: [Chart totals no longer include anonymous* (rare) queries when you apply a query filter.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211453#search_analytics)

Comment: I don't recommend using Google Search Console for traffic analytics, use Google Analytics for better accuracy.

Comment: I'm examining impressions not traffic. It's the focus of my question.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. I tested things and saw the same. It seems that the impressions total is incorrect, but using a page filter corrects it. I've submitted feedback on this, I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Thanks @TonyMcCreath, thought I was going daft. I will do.